# How to fetch value in junit from !unit profiles?

Tags: spring, junit4

I have a configuration file with `@Profile("!unit")`

```
@PropertySource(
    value = {"classpath:abcd-application.properties"},
    ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("abcd"),
```

I have used `@Value("${abcd-application.properties.name})` to give the value of string name. I want this value in my junit to be fetched. I tried adding a bean in the base test but it is not working. I am getting this error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load
>   ApplicationContext......Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name'abcd'...

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***@TestPropertySource*** annotation, this will try to load a properties file relative to the class that declared the annotation.

For more info follow this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-test-property-source)